# Giving Visual Studio and WPF overview guidance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm giving a demo and instroduction of Visual Studio, C# and WPF to C++ on Linux developers that will be soon coding in C#.  My plan is to go over a demo application that explains some basics in C#/WPF and an overview of some of the VS options.

Does anyone have any suggestions on conducting the demo?
Any good websites that can help with overviews?

Comment: Lots of resources are available at http://windowsclient.net/ (specifically the "Learn" tab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Keep the mood light and easy.  They are probably already in bad mood after being told to throw away a good part of their skills and learn a completely different way in order to keep their job.
2. I really hope you are also a c++/linux developer.  You'll need to relate to them somehow.  If not, consider letting someone else give this intro.  If they start complaining in the demo you'll have to know how to bring them back inline.
3. Make sure your demo shows something of real value to them.  For example, "I know you guys solve problem X this way, but with WPF/C# that problem is so much easier because..."
4. The whole thing better be relevant to the fundamental reason why they are being forced to switch.  Cover this, in detail.  Make sure you answer their questions completely.  Be prepared to have your demo derailed by questions.  This could be a Good Thing(TM) as it would hopefully show real engagment.. as long as you keep it positive.
5. Make sure that you have ZERO flaws in your presentation.  Any will be ripped apart, made to appear bigger than it is, and subsequently used as a reason why they shouldn't switch.
6. Under no circumstance should you argue with any of them.  See suggestion #1.
7. Consider enlisting one of "them" to help put the demo together.  Let that person guide some of the covered topics.  This goes a long way towards good will; which you'll need in spades.

I'm making a big assumption that they weren't the ones who drove the decision to switch.  Given the target, it's probably a safe assumption but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm in shameless pursuit of my Electorate badge so this one gets one of my rare +1 for answers.  Great answer!  I would also add that you should introduce them to Mono.  I doubt Mono is complete enough for them to really produce anything production-quality, but it is an opportunity for them to play with the .NET platform in a familiar environment before they make the jump over to the Windows/.NET "dark side" :)

Comment: Great suggestions.  Luckily, the move from c++ to c# is a welcome one.  Just reviewing what Visual Studio can do for them made them want to switch over immediately.

Comment: @Queso: That is great to hear.  I've been on both sides of a tech stack switch, the one driving it and the one being pushed into it.  It was painful either way. Good luck!